# Conveying another user's vision impairment

Tags: accessibility, conventions, games, symbols, serious-game

I'm developing a [serious game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serious_game) for collecting behavioral data and I need to convey to each player some status information about the other players in the game. One piece of information I wish to convey concisely (and thus preferably graphically) is (ironically) if a particular person can see or not.

For example, below is a mockup of a status bar for a game with three players:

[image: Player status bar mockup with indicator for vision impairment]

Is there no more-or-less-conventionalized way of indicating blindness and/or (severe) vision impairment in a multi-user environment to people who can actually see?

Comment: Can you define 'serious'? If you only show faces I would have gone with something like a blindfold but if it's very formal a small icon might be better.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serious_game

Comment: There are a few symbols available to use for indicating Visual Impairment. You can find most of them via Google: https://www.google.de/search?q=visual+impairment+symbol&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji3szKs5zUAhUiMJoKHW25DdoQ_AUICigB&biw=1389&bih=648

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the only state you need to represent is visual impairment, you could have icons to represent that:

[image: Normal vision] [image: Vision Impaired]

These are the Material Design icons for "visibility" on and off, respectively.

What other things do you need to communicate about the players? How does knowing whether or not a player is blind affect how users interact with your game? Providing that context would help you arrive at a better answer.